# Flutter: SliverAppBar disable scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliverappbar

I have SliverAppBar in my app with `expandedHeight: 200,`. Below it i have ListView that display content dynamically and can have different length. If ListView has 7 or more item its works perfecly, but if its below 7 items SliverAppBar still scrolls and has a lot of black space(screenshot). How can i disable SliverAppBar scroll property? I tried to use `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` in ListView itself, it didn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a the `SliverAppBar` in a `CustomScrollView` or similar, you'll need to set the `physics` to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` there as well.

Comment: I don't know how i didn't notice parent NestedScrollView, it worked, thanks

Comment: How i said above, i have NestedScrollView. I added physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), but it didn't prevent me from scrolling